# why do my redux- persist lose data on reload?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-persist

I am using redux persist in my web application to store data in localStorage but redux lose data on page reload. does anybody have the same issue or anybody can help me with this.

my redux-persist initialization is:

```
import { createStore } from "redux";
import userData from "./reducers/reducers";
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from "redux-persist";
import storage from "redux-persist/lib/storage";

const persistConfig = {
  key: "root",
  storage,
  whitelist: ["userData"],
};

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, userData);

const store = createStore(persistedReducer);

export const persistor = persistStore(store);

export default store;
```

while my index.js:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.scss";
import App from "./App";
import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { PersistGate } from "redux-persist/lib/integration/react";
import { persistor } from "./redux/store";
import store from "./redux/store";

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <PersistGate persistor={persistor}>
        <App />
      </PersistGate>
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);

reportWebVitals();
```

I am unable to find any bug or bad practice can anyone help me.

Answer (score 0):

Redux-persist will handle all the stuff. [redux-persist](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist)

Example :

**configureStore.js**

```
    import { createStore } from 'redux'
    import { persistStore, persistReducer } from 'redux-persist'
    import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage' // defaults to localStorage for web and AsyncStorage for react-native
    import rootReducer from './reducers'
    
    const persistConfig = {
      key: 'root',
      storage,
    }
    
    const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer)
    
    export default () => {
      let store = createStore(persistedReducer)
      let persistor = persistStore(store)
      return { store, persistor }
    }
```

**App.js**

```
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react'

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
        <RootComponent />
      </PersistGate>
    </Provider>
  );
};
```

Comment: thanks for your response. still didnt work

Comment: Change `const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, userData);
` to `const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, { userData });
`

Comment: Had you combine your reducer's?

Comment: it give an error ``` TypeError: baseReducer is not a function ```

Comment: no i didn't combine i only have one reducer

Comment: So you can combine your reducer and try it.

Comment: Use `import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
` for combine `combineReducers({ userData })`

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything 'wrong' with your code, the only difference is that you dont have a `rootReducer`, also you dont need to put a `whitelist`, since when I used `whitelist` it didn't filter the others, at least it didn't work for me, what did work for stating which reducer should/shouldn't keep storage was using `blackList` and passing the reducers that wasnt working.

Try giving a shot creating a rootReducer.

Comment: sir userData is my rootReducer

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced it too, make sure the data you want to persist is by calling the reducer that would put a value on the state. ex of authToken.